# Can't set view title in hook_views_views_pre_view

Tags: views

I am trying to change the title of the view based on some conditions view object. I figured that I could simply run

```
drupal_set_title('New title');
```

from inside the hook_views_views_pre_view, but its not changing the title. I tried it in hook_views_query_alter too, but it wouldn't change. I've confirmed that its actually entering the hook by doing a printout of the view object.

Should I be able to set the title from these hooks?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the Views module is calling `drupal_set_title()` right after invoking those hooks, so calling `drupal_set_title()` in those hook doesn't have the effect you are expecting. You could eventually use [`view::set_title`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/view%3A%3Aset_title/7) in [`hook_views_pre_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7) or [`hook_views_pre_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7).

```
function mymodule_views_pre_view(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'the view you need to alter') {
    $view->set_title(t('New title'));
  }
}
```

You cannot assume those hooks are invoked when a view page is being rendered; it could be the view is embedded in a page for which the title change is not desired. This is similar as assuming `hook_node_view()` is being invoked when a node is rendered in its own page, and then calling `drupal_goto()` from that hook.